# Circle moving around the edge of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need a circle moving around the edge of the canvas. Moving right then down is working properly, but when it needs to go left it's jumping to the bottom-right and starts moving right again and again. I don't exactly know how to fix that.

```js
  var can = document.getElementById('C4');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var x = 5, y = 20;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(700, 100, 100, 100);
  function draw() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,0.4)';
      ctx.fill();
      do {//moving right
          x += 2;
      } while (x <! 281);
      if (x >= 280){//down
          do {
              x = 280;
              y += 2;
          } while (y <! 130);
      }
      if(y >= 130 && x >= 280){//left
          do {
              x = x - 2;
              y = 130;
          } while (x >! 20);
      }
      if (x <= 20) {//up
          do {
              x = 20;
              y = y-2;
          } while (y <! 20);
      }

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(34,45,23,0.4)";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  draw();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="C4"></canvas>
```

Comment: What is `<!` supposed to be? Did you probably mean a `<=` in those places?

Comment: This happens because after the circle moves to the left, it triggers the condition to move right again... You could solve this by also checking from what direction the circle was moving. It also helps to put the move direction in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a recursion you don't need the `do while`, the loops are just making the circle jump from one edge to another. You can achive your goal with if conditions, like this:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('C4');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var x = 5, y = 20;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(700, 100, 100, 100);
  function draw() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,0.4)';
      ctx.fill();

      if (x < 280 && y == 20) {
        x += 2;
      }

      if (x >= 280 && y < 130){//down
          x = 280;
          y += 2;
      }

      if(y >= 130 && x > 20){//left
        x = x - 2;
        y = 130;
      }

      if (x == 20 && y > 20) {//up
        x = 20;
        y = y-2;
      }

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(34,45,23,0.4)";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  
  draw();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="C4"></canvas>
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you fixed the first check for moving right too by putting it inside an `if` statement. Great solution

Answer (score 0):

- Isolate the ball as an object.
- Use the balls direction to check for change in direction.
- Clear the canvas first line inside the draw function rather than create a path at the end of the draw function.

Example.

```js
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const radius = 20;
  const speed = 2;
  const ball = {
    style: "rgba(250,0,0,0.4)",
    radius: radius,
    pos: {x: radius, y: radius},
    vel: {x: speed, y: 0},
    step() {
        const w = ctx.canvas.width, h = ctx.canvas.height, r = ball.radius;
        var x = ball.pos.x, y = ball.pos.y
        
        if(ball.vel.x === speed && x >= w - r ) {
            ball.vel.x = 0;
            ball.vel.y = speed;
            ball.pos.x = w - r;
        } else if(ball.vel.y === speed && y >= h - r) {
            ball.vel.x = -speed;
            ball.vel.y = 0;
            ball.pos.y = h - r;
        } else if(ball.vel.x === -speed && x <= r) {
            ball.vel.x = 0;
            ball.vel.y = -speed;
            ball.pos.x = r;
        } else if(ball.vel.y === -speed && y <= r) {        
            ball.vel.x = speed;
            ball.vel.y = 0;
            ball.pos.y = r;
        }
        ball.pos.x += ball.vel.x;
        ball.pos.y += ball.vel.y;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = ball.style;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ball.pos.x, ball.pos.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();    
    },
}

             
        
           
  

  function draw() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(34,45,23,0.4)";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
      ball.step();
      ball.draw();
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  draw();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```